# Python Function Only Returns 0

Tags: python, function, return

This function runs successfully on it's own and correctly calculates the distanceValue:

```
def distance(catRow, mouseRow, catColumn, mouseColumn):
    distanceValue = int( ( (catRow - mouseRow)**2 + (catColumn - mouseColumn)**2 )**(1/2) )
    return distanceValue
```

But what gets returned to the original function is always 0. Why?
Altogether below:

```
def playGame():
    catRow = random.randint(0,MAXROWS)
    mouseRow = random.randint(0,MAXROWS)
    catColumn = random.randint(0,MAXCOLUMNS)
    mouseColumn = random.randint(0, MAXCOLUMNS)

    distanceValue = 0
            
    distance(catRow, mouseRow, catColumn, mouseColumn)
   
    display(catRow, mouseRow, catColumn, mouseColumn, distanceValue)



def distance(catRow, mouseRow, catColumn, mouseColumn):
    distanceValue = int( ( (catRow - mouseRow)**2 + (catColumn - mouseColumn)**2 )**(1/2) )
    return distanceValue  



def display(catRow, mouseRow, catColumn, mouseColumn, distanceValue):
    print("***Current Game Status*** ")
    print("The cat is in row: ", catRow)
    print("The cat is in column: ", catColumn)
    print("The mouse is in row: ", mouseRow)
    print("The mouse is in column: ", mouseColumn)
    print("The distance between the animals is: ", distanceValue)
    print()
```

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the distance value, but then you don't do anything with it. Because `distanceValue` isn't ever updated, it will only ever print 0. You need to modify this line:

```
distance(catRow, mouseRow, catColumn, mouseColumn)
```

**to look like this :-**

```
distanceValue = distance(catRow, mouseRow, catColumn, mouseColumn)
```

Comment: Oh.My.God. Y'all rock. THANK YOU!